# Install Ubuntu alongside an other version of Ubuntu (one drive only available)

Tags: dual-boot

N.B. My configuration is different from the one discussed here: [Adding another Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530343/adding-another-ubuntu) . I have only one drive available-

How can I install Ubuntu version 15 alongside the pre-installed Ubuntu 12 version?

Here is how my computer looks like:

```
NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
sda2   8:2    0 925,4G  0 part /
sda3   8:3    0   5,6G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0   11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

What steps to follow? Please guide me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding another Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/530343/adding-another-ubuntu)

Comment: @Videonauth thanks, but i have only one drive as you can see.

Comment: The same still applies, you just need to resize one partition to have free space.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But I have no free space. Can I shrink the partition `sda2` where Ubuntu 12 is installed to free space?

Comment: You can find out of you have free space on that partition, by right-clicking on computer in nautilus and check the properties. if you have plenty free space on that partition yes you can resize this one to have space for another partition. Advise as always make a backup before you change something around. You might need to recreate the swap and your new partition in a logical volume if the file system is msdos. There are many questions around here already answered on how to resize a partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

You probably don't need 925,4G for Ubuntu 12.(04) . So you can run GParted from live-cd or USB : 1) Reduce sda2 to required size for Ubuntu 12 . ........ 2) Create sda4 as "Extended". .......  3)  Add partitions for new Ubuntu version(s) : The maximum number of partitions is 15 total, if the partition table is DOS.

Gparted http://distrowatch.com/index.php?distribution=gparted&release=all&month=all&year=all

---